# Finding Google Analytics parent account of a tracking code

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics tracking code for a website and I can't find which account it is on. Is there any way of finding which Google account the tracking code belongs to?

I am guessing it is probably impossible due to privacy issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - looks like you need some human intervention:  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=6cc5fc1f1c695073&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Google AdWords support as they seem to handle Analytics issues as well. However you first need to have an AdWords account, so sign up for AdWords (you need not enter any billing information).

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/8206?hl=en

You can choose any option on the above page to contact AdWords support, I chose the email option and they replied back with the restore process.

> Process
>
> Ideally, you would need to contact the administrator, but in your
>   case, I understand that you're unable to place them - and for security
>   reasons, we're unable to disclose administrator information to you.
>   What I can do to help you is write on your behalf to the current
>   administrator/s on this Analytics account, requesting them to get in
>   touch with you.
>
> If you would like me to go ahead and do this, please reply to this
>   email stating so, as this will be the first step.
>
> Next steps
>
> In case this doesn't help and we don't hear back from the
>   administrator (within 7 days from when I write to them), I will share
>   with you the steps to prove ownership of the domain(s) being tracked
>   by this account, and thus gain access to the account independently of
>   the administrator(s).

I was lucky with the first option itself, but it was good to know that I could recover the account by proving domain ownership too.